# Best practice for source control in Azure SQL Database and Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure but very well versed in the old on-prem world of SQL Server/ SSIS/ BI Stack with Redgate source control. In the cloud I am completely lost on how source control should work from a database point of view from changes to stored procedure etc from a Azure Native SQL database point of view. I have dabbled in Data factory and I know it uses Git via Dev Ops on ADF backing up all pipelines etc which is all JSON/ARM. However how do I manage/ deploy changes to SQL server objects like stored proc/functions/views from the databases itself. How can that be sourced controlled?

Any best practices or guidance on this will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Stored Procedures to Version Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370011/how-to-add-stored-procedures-to-version-control)

Comment: Not quite as I was hoping for a way to source control on Azure SQl server Natively, I understand you can get Redgate, but i was thinking how to do it using Dev Ops and git but not sure how to set up source control from a database point of view on azure?

Comment: If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AzureDbUp** : This application was built to help get database changes under source control where they can be rapidly reviewed, audited, and deployed.

To get started, clone this repository to your CI/CD system of choice and have your developers commit sql change scripts files into the sql folders. Then, configure your pipeline to build this repository and execute the built application. When executed, AzureDbUp will make a test connection to your database, and then execute any new sql scripts that have been committed to the repository.

Refer this [github link](https://github.com/TroyWitthoeft/AzureDbUp)

Comment: Thank you, this definitely looks like something I can use for my predicament, cheers